Is there a market cap equivalent for Options Contracts?? (Newbie to Options)
I've been diving into options contracts and have a question about market cap. Is there a direct equivalent for options contracts like there is for stocks?
I've been looking at options on platforms like Yahoo Finance and noticed that many have low liquidity. This makes me wonder how traders at big banks can trade such large volumes of options.
For example, I saw this option contract:
Symbol: TSLA240913P00200000
Underlying: TSLA
Strike price: 200.00
Expiration date: 2024-09-12
Price: 2.7500
Change: +2.1500
Change %: +358.33%
Bid: 2.70
Ask: 2.80
Volume: 41,438
Open interest: 30,640
To calculate a rough estimate of the "market cap" for this option, would I simply multiply the price per contract (2.7500) by the open interest (30,640)? That would give me a market cap of around $84,170. Isn't that abit too small for big traders but yahoo says that is a contract with the highest "Open interest".
I'm still learning the ropes here, so any insights or corrections would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Since Open Interest is in Contracts, and one Contract corresponds to 100 shares, and the price is per share you have to multiply Price * 100 * Contracts. That gives you 8 million dollars. But yes, it is true that many options have low liquidity and they are expensive to trade (compared to stocks).

Yahoo shows exchange-traded activities. There may be more traded "over the counter".

As @DimitriVulis alluded, there is a robust OTC market for equity, FX, fixed income, and commodity derivatives.

TBH, I think this question is a good question and doesn't need to be closed. It is not at all obvious how deep the options markets are, even to a more experienced finance professional, let alone someone relatively new to financial markets.

What hypothetical market participant experience are you trying to characterize?
Equity market capitalization-weighted indices estimate average investor experience and are easy to replicate with a buy-and-hold strategy as the portfolio weights scale up and down with stock price movements (ignoring dividend reinvestment and rebalancing).

(continued)   Maintaining easy replication for your metric may be more difficult for options.  Your weighting scheme will ultimately drive your metric’s option strategy focus  and statistical stationarity characteristics, two considerations which may be in opposition with each other. You might consider a weighting based on vega, open-interest and underlying price of a certain constant (interpolated) duration.
